# Insane dumb question alert: $\varnothing \cup A$ = $A$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am learning $\sigma$ algebra in probability and I just couldn't shake off the feeling that 
$$\varnothing \cup A = A$$ is not true

I know it sounds insane but let me explain

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the $\sigma$- algebra of a set $X$, then $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies:

$\varnothing \in \mathcal{F}$, complement and closure properties.

For example $\mathcal{F} = 2^X = \{\varnothing, x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$

Take $A\subset \mathcal{F}$, $\varnothing \notin A$, for example $A = \mathcal{F} \backslash \varnothing$ then isn't it true $\varnothing \cup A \neq A$?

Confused!

Comment: Alice has three apples.  Bob doesn't give any apples to Alice.  How many apples does Alice have now?

Comment: I think this is an $\varnothing$ vs $\{\varnothing\}$ issue.

Comment: @hardmath Alice has Alzheimer and forgot about her so she don't have any apples anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all $\mathcal F\setminus\emptyset$ is $\mathcal F$ with all elements of the emptyset removed. Since the empty set has no elements, $\mathcal F\setminus \emptyset=\mathcal F$. I think you mean $\mathcal F\setminus\{\emptyset\}=\{x_1,x_2,...\}.$

In the example you gave $\emptyset\cup A$ is the subset of $\mathcal F$ containing all the elements of $A$, and also all the elements of the empty set. But the empty set contains no elements. So $\emptyset\cup A=A$. You may be confusing $\emptyset\cup A$ with $\{\emptyset\}\cup A=\mathcal F$. While the empty set has no elements, $\{\emptyset\}$ has exactly one element (the empty set!)

Comment: Wow I have the brain of a squirrel!

Comment: We all feel that way sometimes.

Comment: @TheSilence Fun story, I wrote a program to help with some research; I was interested in certain subsets of [the set of subsets of vertices] of a graph. I probably spent 5 hours in the beginning debugging various $a$ vs $\{a\}$ vs $\{\{a\}\}$ type errors (computers are quite sensitive to this!) or output that was clearly wrong; it was a nightmare. It helped me become to quite sensitive to the differences, however :)

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal F$ is a **set of sets**, so you really should be considering $\{\emptyset\}$ instead of $\emptyset$. That will give you $\{\emptyset\} \cup A \neq A$.